# Tag synonyms: warnings and compiler-warnings

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Tags [warnings](/questions/tagged/warnings) (2,206 questions tagged) and [compiler-warnings](/questions/tagged/compiler-warnings) (858 questions tagged) seem like they should be synonyms/merged.

I'm not sure of the technical details of concepts of "tag synonyms" and "merging tags" here, and I'm not sure which would be the better tag name, so not suggesting what exactly should be done, yet (and forgive me if this meta question is tagged badly, feel free to fix).

The wiki text could definitely use some improvement after possible merging.

Comment: Honestly, `[warnings]` seems excessively generic.  At least `[compiler-warnings]` is somewhat narrowed down, but still... how much help are these tags when categorizing the question?

Comment: Well, compiler warnings are a concrete thing seen on screen and controlled by switches. Compiler manuals have chapters about them. I don't see how tag for them is any less useful than tag for any other programming related thing.